# Raw SOAP data with WebServices in C#

Tags: c#, soap, request

Where can I find the RAW/object data of a SOAP request in C# when using WebServices.

Can't find it anywhere. Shouldent it be available in the HttpContext.Current.Request object ?

Answer (score 2):

> Shouldent it be available in the HttpContext.Current.Request object ?

No, it shouldn't.

What are you trying to accomplish? If you just want to see that data so you can log it, or as an aid to debugging, then see the example in the [SoapExtension class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapextension.aspx). It's a working sample of an extension that can log input and output as XML. I've used a modified version of it myself.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking to debug your web service, then you can install [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), and that allows you to inspect the data sent to and from your web service.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're going to have to go lower level on your implementation if you want to see the raw XML.  Check out the [generic handler](http://www.aspcode.net/Creating-an-ASHX-handler-in-ASPNET.aspx) (ASHX extension).  This will allow you to deal with the request/response streams directly.  It's very low level, but gives you full control over the service lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

I found

```
Request.Params[null]
```

refers to the RAW data posted to the page in C# ASP.NET.